# Can SQL Server use multiple indexes for the same query?

Tags: sql-server, index, performance, query-performance

This question might have been asked before, but I tried searching with this term "can SQL Server use two indexes for same query" and it yielded no results.

Assume you have the below query:

```
select col1a,colb
from #ab
where col1a in (
Select col1a from #ab 
group by col1a 
having count (distinct colb)>1)
```

And you have the below index:

```
create index nci on #ab(colb)
include(col1a)
```

This is the execution plan, and [Paste The Plan link](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryfDHiQ3Z) as well.

[image: NUTS]

Bottom part of plan is for below query:

```
Select col1a from #ab 
group by col1a 
having count (distinct colb)>1
```

Table scan/top part of plan is for below query:

```
select col1a,colb
from #ab
where col1a in (
```

**Question:**

If I have an index like below:

```
create index nic_toppart on #ab(Col1a,colb)
```

Will it be chosen for top part of plan?

**In summary I meant:**

Can SQL Server use index `nci` for grouping part/bottom part of plan  and use index `nic_toppart` for top part of the plan

Is this possible?

My tests show it can only choose one.

Below is test data. Please let me know if I am unclear.

```
create table #ab
(
col1a int,
colb char(2)
)

insert into #ab
values
(1,'a'),
(1,'a'),
(1,'a'),
(2,'b'),
(2,'c'),
(2,'c')

select col1a,colb
from #ab
where col1a in (
Select col1a from #ab 
group by col1a 
having count (distinct colb)>1)


create index nci on #ab(colb)
include(col1a)

create index nci_p on #ab(col1a,colb)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, but not with the indexes you've chosen.

If I create these indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_top ON #ab (col1a) INCLUDE (colb);

CREATE INDEX ix_bottom ON #ab (colb, col1a);
```

I get back [this plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1o-OjXhW):

[image: NUTS]

And that's without having to use [multiple index hints](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/05/bad-idea-jeans-multiple-index-hints/).

With a slightly different index:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_mindyourbusinessypercube ON #ab (col1a, colb);
```

[The plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJfEpjQ3W) changes to use just that one index, though performance ramifications are difficult to surmise given the limited test data. I leave that as an exercise to <del>ypercube</del> the reader.

[image: NUTS]